# Unable to start postgres after changing to nologin

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, security, unix

Due to security recommendations i have changed in /etc/passwd

```
postgres:x:26:26:PostgreSQL Server:/var/lib/pgsql:/bin/bash
```

to

```
postgres:x:26:26:PostgreSQL Server:/var/lib/pgsql:/sbin/nologin
```

after that i am unable to restart my postgres server 
i am getting error:

> This account is currently not available

Comment: This question is off-topic, and you provide way too little information: which operating system ? Which version? How is PostgreSQL started? What does the startup script look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `chsh` command changes your shell (or by using `sudo` the shell for another user. And, since you are not able to login, you *must* execute this command as another user)

---

```
sudo chsh postgres -s /bin/bash
```